# Sharelatex: Centered and left-adjusted text in section not working

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment

I'm working in a document with two vertically seperated sections. Currently I have two version as can be seen in the screenshot: [image]

I want to combine the properties of the two. That is to center the text inside the sections (lower section) and also to adjust the text to the left (upper section). My code is:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{comment}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

Test\\

Test + Test\\

Test + Test + Test\\

Test + Test + Test + Test\\

Test\\

Test + Test\\

Test + Test + Test\\

\columnbreak

Test + Test + Test + Test\\

\end{multicols}


\begin{multicols}{2}

\center Test\\

Test + Test\\

Test + Test + Test\\

Test + Test + Test + Test\\

\columnbreak

Test\\

Test + Test\\

Test + Test + Test\\


Test + Test + Test + Test\\

\end{multicols}
```

Tried to use this [link](http://www.bollchen.de/blog/2010/07/block-centered-alignment-inside-latex-tables/) but it backfired.

Comment: never end a paragaraph with `\\ ` !!

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle. Thx for the tip! Do you have any suggestions regarding the alignment?

Comment: Also `article` does not have a `14pt` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want a centred block set flush left, or perhaps a left aligned block, centred:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{comment}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Test\\
Test + Test\\
Test + Test + Test\\
Test + Test + Test + Test
\end{tabular}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
Test\\
Test + Test\\
Test + Test + Test\\
Test + Test + Test + Test
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked! Thx.